# CellC data card not recognized if I boot with it in

Tags: 11.10, broadband

In 11.10 I find that I can connect to the internet via broadband connection successfully. The problem is that I cannot have the data card attached to the machine while the machine boots up. If I leave the data card in the machine during startup, the data card is not picked up and I then cannot connect to the internet. 
I must first boot up my machine, login, attach the data card into the usb port, wait so 30 seconds. The broadband connection name will then appear in the network dropdown at the top of the screen. An internet connect is now possible via broadband.

Please let me know what must be done to fix this.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I use a broadband too, and generally I have to plug in the whole thing after I login. It may just be that Ubuntu doesn't have very good support of this type of hardware.

Comment: Sure thanks, I can live with it. As long as the users know and understand how it works. Its just the first thing I noticed after upgrading from the previous version. Also, the windows environments dont have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

OP Does not want solution

> Sure thanks, I can live with it. As long as the users know and understand how it works. Its just the first thing I noticed after upgrading from the previous version. Also, the windows environments dont have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile broadband modems are not as well supported on Linux as Windows, it generally relates to incompatibility of the drivers and network manager detection issues.

[The Ubuntu Wiki for 3G data cards](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NetworkManager/Hardware/3G) is a useful resource for which cards work better than others and what steps/settings may need to be followed for getting them working.

I also found a good question that may be of some help on the [Unix & Linux StackExchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29473/difficulty-with-mobile-broadband-device-being-recognized-registered-as-cd-rom) that gives some detailed set up instructions to help cards get recognised and working.